# What is the lang function in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, multilingual, blazegraph

Among the [SPARQL Query Examples](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/SPARQL_Query_Examples), there is a [query for US presidents and spouses](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/SPARQL_Query_Examples#US_presidents_and_spouses):

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX v: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>

SELECT ?p ?w ?l ?wl WHERE {
  wd:Q30 p:P6/v:P6 ?p .
  ?p wdt:P26 ?w .
  OPTIONAL  {  
    ?p rdfs:label ?l filter (lang(?l) = "en") . 
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?w rdfs:label ?wl filter (lang(?wl) = "en"). 
  }
}
```

It contains function-like syntax, `lang(?l)`, which is intended to filter by language.

How does this work? Is this a special function of *Blazegraph*? Or are different languages stored as normal values in RDF graphs?

How can I store data this way, so that it will be retrieved with the `lang` function correctly?

May I have my own function to have ND predicates, like `probability(?a) > 0.8`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lang` is a native SPARQL operator (see [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#func-lang)) which returns the language tag of an [RDF literal](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#h3_section-Graph-Literal) (e.g. the `EN` in `?p foaf:name "Robert"@EN.`).

Some SPARQL engines support the ability to implement custom functions. See for example [this tutorial for Sesame](http://www.rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/creating-custom-sparql-functions/) and [this for Blazegraph](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/CustomFunction).

Comment: So, the "tag" concept disobeys RDF model?

Comment: @SuzanCioc, no the language tag is actually defined as part of [RDF literals](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#h3_section-Graph-Literal)